# The ambiguity of the phrase "we disagree"

Tags: meaning

Let us consider such a phrase:

> Ashley and I disagree on this subject.

As far as I understand it means that Ashley and the speaker have different opinions on the subject. But is not there some ambiguity? I mean the following:

> Ashley and I disagree *[with Fred]* on this subject.

That is, depending on the context, it may mean that Ashley and the speaker share an opinion and it is different from that of Fred.

**Thus, can *A and B disagree* have two meanings as described above?**

Comment: I agree with you. The context might help. For example, if Tom says that he wants chocolate, it would make sense to respond "Ashley and I disagree; we both want vanilla." But if someone then asks what the three of you want, it might be clear to respond "We disagree," now meaning that you disagree with each other. But "we disagree" is not unusual; lots of expressions depend on context for their meaning.

Answer (score 3):

In your first sentence, there is no ambiguity, since you are saying that you and Ashley are discussing a subject on which your opinions differ.

However, in the second sentence, you and Ashley might *still* disagree on the subject, but neither of your opinions is the same as Fred's. It can also mean that you and Ashley share the same opinion - which differs from Fred's opinion - but this difference cannot be derived from the sentence.